# How to stop Windows Auto leveling on audio (mic specifically)

Tags: windows, registry, microphone

Hello Stackoverflow community!

My mic always sets itself on 100, but i don't want that to happen.

[image: That's what i want]

[image: That's what i get (my Problem)]

Since i sound like a earrape guy on teamspeak for the users. And i don't want that. How do i change this? Can i modify the registry somehow? Or change the default value for the normal mic Setting for good?

I couldn't really try anything but manually reseting the mic-level bymyself. But that is not permanently.

I'd be greatful to find some good answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile, i have written a little program myself which fixes the issue for me.
It sets the volume to 70%
Read the Readme file for more information

https://www.dropbox.com/s/rw4962krpwgqxax/Stop%20Auto-Leveling.zip?dl=0